# slf4j-log4j bridge with log4j 2.8.1

Tags: log4j, slf4j, log4j2, bridge

I am working on removing any dependencies on log4j 1.x versions as they have EOL'd. My code uses slf4j-log4j12 bridge. In maven central compile dependencies for slf4j-log4j shows log4j at version 1.2.17 with updates column showing 2.8.1.

So I tried following in build.gradle with the hope that log4j-api-2.8.1 would be used in place of log4j-1.2.17 which is pulled by default. But that doesn't seem to be working. I still see log4j-1.2.17 in the dependent jars.

So I wanted to ask, is this something that is not allowed at all? I.e. there is no slf4j-log4j bridge to log4j 2.8.1 version or for that matter 2.x version? Essentially I should migrate my code to use log4j-api-2.8.1. Or am I missing something here?

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.8.1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.25'   
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`slf4j-log4j12` is a binding for log4j version 1.2. But you need log4j version 2 (log4j2) binding, which is named `log4j-slf4j-impl`.

To use slf4j along with log4j2, you will require:

- log4j-api (2.8.1)
- log4j-core (2.8.1)
- log4j-slf4j-impl (2.8.1)
- slf4j-api (1.7.25)

If you have any implementation and/or dependency over log4j version 1.2, you will also require:

- log4j-1.2-api (2.8.1)

However, you should not include following dependencies in any case:

- log4j-to-slf4j (2.x)
- log4j (1.2.x)

Comment: One question, don't know if I should put it in my main question. Slf4j 1.7.25 page [here](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/index.html) lists org.apache.log4j.* packages towards end. But the actual jar doesn't contain any of those. I am not able to understand what is happening here. Please help. Also Log4j-api-2.8.1 packages are now namespaced as org.apage.logging.log4j.* So how does this fit with Sl4j-api 1.7.25...?

Comment: @WinCPP: I think, org.apache.log4j.* packages in slf4j apidocs are of "log4j-to-sl4j". That's why these aren't in main api. And the implementation of fitting with slf4j is in "log4j-sl4j-impl".

Comment: @Mike HM Thanks for noticing the typo.

Comment: I needed log4j-slf4j2-impl