# log4j2 upgrade with the reference of log4j1

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I am upgrading my application to log4j2. Currently my application has log4j1. But after upgrade i found one of the external API (abc.jar) still using log4j1. When i run my application i get error
 `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger`

I know i can fix by adding log4j1 dependency to classpath or i can use the similar external API (abc.jar) which uses log4j2. but my end goal is to not use log4j1.

Is there any way i can handle my current external API (abc.jar) which is still looking for log4j1 to avoid  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger` ?

Comment: The slf4j project has a bridge class that bridges from log4j1.2 to slf4j.  If you then add the slf4j -> log4j2 backend, you now have a path ...

Comment: If your application used slf4j itself, you would be in a better position.

Comment: @StephenC, can you please share some example? my application is very old and having 400 java files.. now i am just having issue with only abc.jar which is still using log4j1.. how i can handle this abc.jar using slf4j-->log4j2?

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-1.2-api/index.html or https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159201/139985 or many more

Comment: The other alternative is to fix the source code for "abc.jar" and recompile it.  The age of your code is not directly relevant.